# what is the difference between long and long raw data types in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

My understanding is Long data type can store the actual string(chars), while Long raw data type stores the binary values of the string(chars). Is it right? Can a table have only one long type column?

Comment: Oracle LONG datatypes are available for backward compatibility only. Better look into BLOB/CLOB datatypes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The data types are described in the documentation; [`LONG` is explained here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i45885) (or the [11gR2 version](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i45885)):

> LONG columns store variable-length character strings containing up to
>   2 gigabytes -1, or 231-1 bytes. LONG columns have many of the
>   characteristics of VARCHAR2 columns. You can use LONG columns to store
>   long text strings.

And [`LONG RAW` is here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i46018):

> The RAW and LONG RAW datatypes store data that is not to be
>   interpreted (that is, not explicitly converted when moving data
>   between different systems) by Oracle Database. These datatypes are
>   intended for binary data or byte strings. For example, you can use
>   LONG RAW to store graphics, sound, documents, or arrays of binary
>   data, for which the interpretation is dependent on the use.

So a `RAW` or `LONG RAW` can contain the binary representation of characters, but won't be subject to character set conversion etc. so probably isn't all that useful for that; an can contain any other binary data - anything that isn't supposed to represent text.

From the same `LONG` section:

> A table can contain only one LONG column.

However, `LONG` is deprecated in favour of `LOB` (`CLOB` or `NCLOB` for text, `BLOB` for everything else), so you shouldn't be using them for new work, and should at least be considering replacing any you already have. Again from that same section on `LONG`:

> Do not create tables with LONG columns. Use LOB columns (CLOB, NCLOB,
>   BLOB) instead. LONG columns are supported only for backward
>   compatibility.
>
> Oracle also recommends that you convert existing LONG columns to LOB
>   columns.

This [documentation on migrating from `LONG` to `LOB`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_long_lob.htm) might be of interest.